# Fit a curve with unknown function assuming normal errors

Tags: normal-distribution, error

Let say that I have a 1D experimental dataset $y(x)$, which contains noise due to experimental error. Is it possible to estimate the data by assuming that the errors are normally distributed? (The true shape of the data is unknown otherwise this is reduced to a fitting problem)

The scipy gaussian filter (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html) is almost doing what I want but perform badly at boundaries (start and end values).

Comment: "Estimate the data"?  Please explain what that might mean.  What would such an estimate be based on??

Comment: The data experimentally obtained can be seen as being the 'true' data (without the noise, if the instruments were perfect) plus some noise. If you make an assumption on the noise (gaussian), is it possible to estimated the 'true' data?

Comment: It might depend on what you mean by "1D" and "$y(x),$" but it sounds like you are asking to estimate at least as many parameters as you have data values, which leaves you no degrees of freedom to assess the quality of your estimate: in other words, it looks grossly overfit.  But Gaussian filters don't work the way you describe: they make strong assumptions about the data.  This suggests you will need to describe your application and reveal your assumptions if you wish to make any progress toward a solution.